# set target.id to div id and a number?

Tags: jquery

The target id below is map_external, but I would like to get map_external(and a number)

I have this:

```
$('#jqt').bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e, info){
           if (e.target.id == 'map_external') {
                 if (info.direction =='in') {
                    localiser();
                }
```

and it works, and my target page looks like this:

```
<div id="map_external">
content....
</div>
```

but I would like to have a random number aswell, like this:

```
<div id="map_external<%=asp random number%>">
content....
</div>
```

so how do i write  if (e.target.id == 'map_external') so that it gets map_external and a number(any number)?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you going to have only one such div or generate more than one div with different id appended by the random number?

Answer (score 2):

Try writing it like this:

```
var newId = e.target.id;
if (newId.indexOf("map_external") > -1) { // will test for the first instance, and find it at 0
        if (info.direction =='in') {
            localiser();
        }
}
```

Comment: `.indexOf()` is a good solution here. Only thing I would change is to check against `=== 0`,  so we know that `map_external` is at the beginning and not anywhere in the id string.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure how to test for a **true** FALSE, like in PHP `=== FALSE`. So I resorted to testing for 0 or more.

Comment: ëtte: since `.indexOf()` returns the index if it finds an occurence and otherwise `-1`, it's pretty convinient to excplicitly check for `0` if you want to know if the occurence is at the beginning.

Comment: @jAndy: I was just making it more dynamic for if the `id` doesn't necessarily begin with **map_external** but it does occur in the `id`, but thanks, I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 1):

Try matching it against a Regex:

```
if (e.target.id.match(/^map_external\d+/)) {
    // id matches "map_external{number}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the attribute contains prefix selector in jQuery http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-prefix-selector/

```
  $('#jqt[id|="map_external"]').bind('pageAnimationStart', function(e, info){

             if (info.direction =='in') {
                localiser();
            }
  });
```

Comment: I will have a couple of pages with the map_external id, thats why I need to get it with a random number. Does this change anything?

Comment: No the idea of the contains prefix selector is that it will match the start of the string e.g. |="map_external" will match "map_external_anything", "map_external2313908", "map_external"

Comment: unless you meant the #jpt is going to change in which case you could just use $('*[id|="map_external"]').bind...

Comment: Hi Rob and thanks, no the #jqt will stay the same, I will test it. It looks like what I need.

Comment: It seams to work, some bit, it gets the pages and that part seams ok, but now it doesnt display the googlemaps and I guess that it has to do with the case "map_external" in the below:
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            $(function(){
                $('body').bind('turn', function(event, info){
                    var curr = $(".current").attr("id");
                    switch (curr) {
                    case "map_external"       :
                      if (info.orientation == "landscape") {

How can I get that to get map_external and the number?